# Python - 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Есть функция, при вызове её через `GET` запрос, она показывает нынешнею дату и время.

```
@app.route('/date', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
now = datetime.datetime.now()
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d['status'] = 200
d['isoTime'] = now.isoformat()
d['year'] = now.year()
d['month'] = now.month()
d['day'] = now.month()
d['hour'] = now.hour()
d['minute'] = now.minute()
d['secord'] = now.second()
d['weekday'] = now.weekday()
d['timeZone'] = now.timetz()
if request.method == 'GET':
    return flask_json.dumps(d, sort_keys=False, indent=True)
else:
    return 'POST'
```

При запуске функции, появляется ошибка - `TypeError: 'int' object in not callable`

Comment: на какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy начиная от `now.year`, заканчивая `now.second`

Comment: [справка](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html): `date.year
Between MINYEAR and MAXYEAR inclusive.` То есть это число а не функция

Comment: Вообще и из текста ошибки без всяких справок должно быть очевидно, что это готовые числа и скобки надо убрать

Comment: в сторону: 1- `datetime.now()` возвращает `datetime` *без* информации о текущей временной зоне 2- `timetz()` возвращает `datetime.time()` а не `timezone` 3- Чтобы передать текущее время на сервере, можно `int(time.time())` послать и/или `datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z'` 4- чтобы руками имена аттрибутов не печатать дважды: `d = OrderedDict((attr, getattr(now, attr)) for attr in "year month day hour minute second".split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[8.1.4. datetime Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

> Instance attributes (read-only):
>
> datetime.year
>   Between MINYEAR and MAXYEAR inclusive.
>
> datetime.month
>   Between 1 and 12 inclusive.
>
> datetime.day
>   Between 1 and the number of days in the given month of the given year.
>
> datetime.hour
>   In range(24).
>
> datetime.minute
>   In range(60).
>
> datetime.second
>   In range(60).

Как видно из справки - данные поля не являются функциями и при обращении к ним не нужны `()`

В то время как [timetz](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetz) и [weekday](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) - это методы и в их случае нужны.